# Decode String (in Data Class) as Date in Kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, date, google-cloud-firestore

How would i decode a string, contained in a data class, as a date.
I have several strings, which are actually dates `("2022-11-24T23:37:34.668Z")`. These are stored within documents in firebase (obviously there are not only date strings in the documents, but also other types).
I want to deserialize so that the strings, which represent dates, are autmatically parsed as such.

Currently i decode like so:

```
private inline fun <reified T> parse(snapshot: DocumentSnapshot?): T? {
     return snapshot?.toObject<T>(T::class.java)
}
```

I do not see a way how to specify a date decoder. Therefore, how do i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed no way to specify a custom decoder for a specific field/property.

The best options I can quickly think of are:

- Add custom functions to the data class to parse the string to a date, and to set a new value as a date and [marking them as excluded](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/Exclude) from the database.
- Define a custom class for the string field (e.g. `StringDate`), which handles the same parsing and serializing and then use that in your data class.

I don't know of existing public implementations of either of these.

Of course the easiest option would be to store the date/time value in a [`Timestamp` field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types) that the Firestore SDK then automatically convert to the native date/time type on each supported platform.

Comment: What do you mean, store the date/ time in a `Timestamp` field.

Comment: Check the `Date and time` in the [list of supported data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) and the section on [writing data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types) in the documentation.